# system command not working at aws server

Tags: php, zip

I am creating zip using system command but is it not working.Showing this error

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$sys = system("zip -r -P pass pkr.zip test.txt");
var_dump($sys);
exit();
```

this is showing error string(0)

Comment: Can you clarify this some? What do you mean by "aws server"? Is the zip library installed?

Comment: I am using Amazon web service for hosting.

Comment: try putting the full path to the files in the system command

Comment: well i don't know what is the question here in fact, because like i see from the `zip` manual, if the exit code is 0 than that means this 
`0
normal; no errors or warnings detected.`

Comment: @PankajYogi some AWS pre-built instances come fairly 'naked' ... have you logged-in to your instance and tried your zip command ? In the proper directory ? with the appropriate user ?

Comment: I try putting full path but zip not created yet.

Comment: Using  this $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .